# PowerShell: Processing multiple API Posts in parallel

Tags: json, powershell, parallel-processing

First PowerShell script I've written (removed some details from the code - but it runs just fine).  I'm splitting a CSV file up into 30 MB chunks.  I was wondering how I could speed up the Posts (it's currently sequentially Posting - and I'd like it to be parallel). Any ideas?

```
# Iterates through each 30MB (or less) batch of rows - how can I speed this up?
for ($i=0; $i -lt $NumJobs; $i++)
{
    [int]$StartRow = ($i * $JobRows)
    [int]$EndRow=(($i+1) * $JobRows - 1)
    write-host ("Rows {0} to {1}" -f $StartRow.ToString(),$EndRow.ToString())

    $CSVRows = $csv[$StartRow..$EndRow]
    $json = ($CSVRows | ConvertTo-Json -Compress)


        # Create API authorization signature
        Function Build-Signature (some params)
        {
            ...
        }


        # Create Post Request
        Function Post-Data(some params)
        {
            ...
        }

        # Post this chunk of JSON to API endpoint
        Post- ... JSON chunk 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use parallel processing modules. For example:

- https://github.com/nightroman/SplitPipeline (my recomendations)
- https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/Invoke-Parallel
- https://github.com/powercode/PSParallel